# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I upgraded my solution from MVC 3 to MVC 4 due to required code (DayPilot MVC - Calendar Controls).  Everything works on my laptop, where I developed the project, now I need to push this to UAT, and on the server, I get this following error:

[image: Server Error]

I tried to install the MVC version via nuget, and update everything, and still nothing.  Any ideas where to look or what to change, will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go to the nugget console:
and run this:

```
Update-Package -Reinstall
```

The nugget console is in vs2012: Tools/Library Package Manager / Package Manager Console:
https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console

and In vs2013: Tools/Nuget Package manager / PAckage manager console

you need to Update the references to the one that you use in a MVC4 web app (check the .NET framework you are using in the properties of the solution and check that match 3.5 or above

Comment: Some more information about nugget packages 
http://blog.nuget.org/20121231/a-quick-tutorial-on-update-package-command.html